# Youtube URL-style hashes

Tags: php, hash

I'm trying to find out how to build nice and short alpha numeric hashes like the kind used in youtube urls.

Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rw71YOSXhpE

Where rw71YOSXhpE would convert into video number 12834233 (for example).

These integers could be reversed in PHP to an integer and then looked up in a database.

I've run the following in PHP:

```
<?
$algoList = hash_algos( );

foreach( $algoList as $algoName )
{
    echo $algoName . ": " . hash( $algoName, 357892345234 ) . "\n";
}
?>
```

But none of them come back with characters beyond the a-f you'd expect.  Youtube have the whole english alphabet in upper and lower case.  Any idea how they've done it?

Comment: Nitpick: Since you can reverse it, it's not a *hash* but rather an *encoding*.

Comment: Youtube now uses base 64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [base_convert()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) to convert your number into base 36, which uses 0-9 plus a-z, and which has the advantage that your URL parameter is not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 6):

You want to convert your integer to a different base, one which uses the full alphabet. Base64 could work but you will get strings which are longer than the original integer because the base64_encode() function takes a string, not an integer.

My suggestion would be to use the base_convert() function like so:

```
$id = 12834233;
$hash = base_convert($id, 10, 36);
```

and the reverse

```
$hash = '7n2yh'
$id = base_convert($hash, 36, 10);
```

This however will only use lowercase letters a-z and 0-9. If you wish to use all upper and lower case letters you would need to convert to base 62 (or higher if you use symbols). However to do this you will have to write your own code.

**Edit**: Gordon pointed out this [great link](http://programanddesign.com/php/base62-encode/) to base62 encoding in php.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, and wrote a class for myself just for this.

Documentation: http://www.hashids.org/php/

Souce: https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php

You would use it like this:

```
require('lib/Hashids/Hashids.php');

$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('salt value', 11);
$hash = $hashids->encrypt(12834233);
```

You would get the following `$hash`: **Rz0zlKZGg6g**

Provide your own unique string for the salt value. The 11 in the code is optional and stands for minimum hash length. (You can also define your own alphabet string as 3rd param to the constructor).

To decrypt the hash you would do this:

```
$numbers = $hashids->decrypt($hash);
```

So `$numbers` will be: `[12834233]`

(It's an array because hashids can encrypt/decrypt several numbers into one hash.)

**EDIT**:

1. Changed urls to include both doc website and code source
2. Changed example code to adjust to the main lib updates (current PHP lib version is 0.3.0 - thanks to all the open-source community for improving the lib)

Comment: I am referring to a hash a string of characters. Why can't they be decryptable and unique at the same time?

Comment: :) I think you are focusing on the word more than on the code. You can call it a hash, or id, or whatever you prefer. And if you look closely at the answer, I state that 11 is the minimum hash length - some of the characters are there simply for padding.

Comment: I think you simply rated me on the wording (which you disagree with), not on the solution to the original problem that I tried to help with. I also think it's worth taking a look at the code (which is open source) before accusing me of "falsely stat[ing]" something. Seems a bit unfair.

Comment: I said minimum hash length, not exact hash length. And the website points to documentation page which does not and will not have ads -- it actually costs me money to host it. (edited the post to update examples to latest Hashids lib and link to github source as well)

Comment: If your point is to win *any* kind of argument (since you are jumping from one to the other), we can be commenting here forever. I told you already the word hash is used loosely to refer to what the OP posted about and not in pure-cryptographic way.

Comment: Just a note. Strings which were md5'ed it makes hashes just 2-3 chars shorter, so it is probably worth to be mentioned in docs somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

probably a base64 encoding of a (part of) an md5 ? although I seems to recall that there are short ones and long ones, so it could be md5 or sha1.
if you base64 decode the token you gave, with proper padding, the result is an 8 bit entity, so it's not a full md5. It could be only the first half of it.

Answer (score -2):

Something similar could be done with [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

Comment: But base64 includes characters like '='